# SQL: show description in text instead of bit value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an attribute declared as bit: (true or false).

For example:

```
SELECT myBit FROM [table]
```

=> it will show: 1 or 0

I would like to show: 'Valid' and 'Invalid' for 1 and 0 respectively.

How could I add IF ELSE statement in the SELECT statement?

Comment: What version of SQL?  SQL Server, MySQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For SQL Server, you can use a [**CASE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement:

```
SELECT CASE myBit WHEN 1 THEN 'Valid' WHEN 0 THEN 'Invalid' END As MyColumn
FROM [table]
```